Kitchen aid is noisy at medium speeds
My kitchen aid stand mixer is noisy only at speeds 3-6.  It sounds normal at low or high speeds.  We greased it, but it was still noisy.  We read that it may not have enough grease, so we added more, but that did not help.

KitchenAid has a great service program. For a fixed cost they send you a shipping container, which you return with your mixer in. We've done this twice with 2 different KitchenAid mixers. They come back acting (and sounding) new.
